# 1. Please explain this solution to Rectangle Rotation on Codesignal.com 2. Please explain why my solution doesn't work

Tags: algorithm, trigonometry

I found a simple solution that I don't understand. Here is the code.

```
def rectangleRotation(a, b):
    pt = 0
    radius = pow(a/2,2)+pow(b/2,2)
    radius = int(math.ceil(pow(radius,.5)))

    for i in range(-radius,radius+1):
        for j in range(-radius,radius+1):
            x = i*math.cos(math.radians(-45)) - j*math.sin(math.radians(-45))
            y = i*math.sin(math.radians(-45)) + j*math.cos(math.radians(-45))
            if -a/2<=x<=a/2 and -b/2<=y<=b/2:
                pt += 1
    return pt
```

The problem statement is

> "A rectangle with sides equal to even integers a and b is drawn on the Cartesian plane. Its center (the intersection point of its diagonals) coincides with the point (0, 0), but the sides of the rectangle are not parallel to the axes; instead, they are forming 45 degree angles with the axes.
>   How many points with integer coordinates are located inside the given rectangle (including on its sides)?"

I tried to solve the problem using sohcahtoa and have written a bunch of equations down for smaller parts of the rectangle including the y intercept for the upper and rightmost lines. I calculated the valid x range using trig. I also calculated where the upper and lower bound of the rectangle changes.
My code is much more complex than the solution, and I understand if people don't want to answer the second part of my problem, but it would help me a lot.

```
int rectangleRotation(int a, int b) {
    // let y1 be the y intercept for the upper line of the rectangle     
    double y1 = b/sqrt(2);
    // let y2 be the y intercept for the right line of the rectangle
    double y2 = a/sqrt(2);
    // let xyrange be the ceil of the range of x and y
    int xyrange = floor((sqrt(2)/4)*(a + b));
    // let x1 be the point at which the lower/upper line changes
    double x1 = (sqrt(2)/4)*(a - b);
    // let points be the number of points within the rectangle
    int points = 0;
    for (int i = -xyrange; i <= xyrange; i++) {
        // let ru be the floor of upper line value of the rectangle at i
        double ru;
        // check if the upper line changed
        if (i >= ceil(x1)) {
            ru = -i + y2;
        } else {
            ru = i + y1;
        }
        // let rui be the integer bound for the upper line
        int rui;
        if (ru <= 0) {
            rui = ceil(ru);
        } else {
            rui = floor(ru);
        }
        // let rl be the ceil of lower line value of the rectangle at i
        double rl;
        // check if the lower line changed
        if (i <= -floor(x1)) {
            rl = -i - y2;
        } else {
            rl = i - y1;
        }
        // let rui be the integer bound for the upper line
        int rli;
        if (rl <= 0) {
            rli = ceil(rl);
        } else {
            rli = floor(rl);
        }
        for (int j = -xyrange; j <= xyrange; j++) {
            if (j <= rui && j >= rli) {
                points++;
            }
        }
    }
    return points;
}
```

I get an answer that is too high for most of the test cases, and varies from 5 to 50 above the correct answer depending on the value of a and b, the higher a and b the more the difference is. For a = 6 and b = 4 I expect an output of 23 but I get 27.

Comment: 1. It's beyond the scope of Stack Overflow to give you an end-to-end explanation of a posting.  Rather, *you* should explain where you're lost: ask a *specific* question.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.

Comment: "I get an answer that is too high" is not a problem specification, but your one example does help.  However, we'd expect you to make some attempt to debug the logic, rather than posting this as a "black box" error.  Where did your calculations deviate from expectations?  You have a lot of abbreviated intermediate variables that you haven't checked.

Comment: See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't we just have a direct formula,

```js
function f(a, b){
  let big = Math.max(a, b)
  let small = Math.min(a, b)

  let NE_x_y = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(big * big / 8))
  let width = 2 * NE_x_y + 1
  let half_height = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(small * small / 8))
  let height = 2 * half_height + 1

  let rectangle_1 = width * height

  let hypotenuse = Math.sqrt(2 * NE_x_y * NE_x_y) + 1 / Math.sqrt(2)

  let rectangle_2_w

  if (hypotenuse <= big / 2)
    rectangle_2_w = width + 1
  else
    rectangle_2_w = width - 1

  let rectangle_2_h = 2 * (Math.floor((small / 2 - 1/Math.sqrt(2)) / Math.sqrt(2)) + 1)

  return rectangle_1 + rectangle_2_w * rectangle_2_h
}

console.log(f(6, 4))
```

using Pythagoras?

Answer (score 1):

To attempt to explain the first code, what's more telling, perhaps, are the enumerated coordinates that *don't* get counted towards the solution.

```
x' = x cos(θ) - y sin(θ)
y' = x sin(θ) + y cos(θ)
```

are the coordinates for a point, `(x, y)`, rotated `θ` radians.

If we consider that the rectangle's diagonal is the diameter of the circle within which the problem's rotation happens, we see that the program seeks to enumerate all lattice points for that circle rotated by 45 degrees. Then the last `if` statement makes sure only those rotated lattice points in the circle that fall within the arbitrary bounds of the rectangle are counted (notice that since all lattice points are enumerated, it doesn't matter if we flip `a` and `b`, the parameters of the rectangle's sides, since the `if` statement restricts the chosen coordinates by a fixed relation to both sides).